# Arraylist and display

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my class below:

```
package classregisterapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ClassRegister 
{
   private String[] studentNames;
   private String tutGrp;

   public ClassRegister(String[] studentNames, String tutGrp) 
   {
      this.studentNames = studentNames;
      this.tutGrp = tutGrp;
   }

   public String getTutGrp()
   {
      return tutGrp;
   }

   public void searchStudent(String name)
   {
      if (name == tutGrp)
      {
         System.out.println("Student found");
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("Student not found");
      }
   }
}
```

This below is my main:

```
package classregisterapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClassRegisterApp 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      ArrayList<ClassRegister> classList = new ArrayList<>();

      ClassRegister cr1= new ClassRegister ("Ron", "T09");
      ClassRegister cr2 = new ClassRegister ("Mandy", "T09");
      ClassRegister cr3 = new ClassRegister ("Joshua", "T09");

      classList.add(cr1);
      classList.add(cr2);
      classList.add(cr3);

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter student name: ");
   }
}
```

1) Create a ClassRegister object with a tutorial group consisting of students (“Ron”, “Mandy”, “Joshua”) and tutorial group name as “T09”.

2) Read in a name from the user and find out whether the student is in the tutorial group. Display message “Student found” if the student is found. Otherwise, display message “Student not found”.

When I did `ClassRegister cr1= new ClassRegister ("Ron", "T09")`..., the "Ron" is underlined in red, line 12 to 14 of it, says "String cannot be converted to String[]". I wonder what the error is and not sure on how to ask the user to check if the student is in the class or even am I doing the right way?

Comment: "Ron" is a `String`, but your constructor needs an array of `String`, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @shree.pat18 how do i go about changing it or do i change the way i write on the main? the class for the student names, it has to be an arrayList<string>

Comment: @lexus it's not clear what were you planning to do since `studentNames` is never used...

Comment: @alfasin studentNames is at the main class to input the details isnt?

Comment: Again, are you using `studentNames` ? if so - please show us where and how.

Comment: @alfasin ClassRegister cr1= new ClassRegister ("Ron", "T09")... "Ron" and "T09", isnt it using the constructor of classRegister? And was asking how do i go about tackling the String cannot be converted to String[] and at point 2

Comment: @lexus I didn't ask about the contractor. I was asking about the very specific class member called `studentNames`. Other than reading into to it - it's never used.

Comment: In your `searchStudent(String name)` method, I think you should compare two strings by *equals* instead of *==* .

Answer (score 0):

class `ClassRegister` constructor accepts as the first argument an array of strings and you pass in only a single string., for example:

```
ClassRegister cr1= new ClassRegister ("Ron", "T09");
                                        ^
```